# iOS Status Bar changing color to match navigation bar on its own

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController in my AppDelegate with a RootViewController that has a UITableView. On startup, the status bar changes its color to the color of the navigation bar. When I colored my navigation bar to orange, this is what the status bar is looking like:

[image]

It seems that my navigation bar is shifted to the top a little bit. It appears that the navigation controller does not recognize the status bar. How can I fix this issue?

The only thing I have in my app is an AppDelegate and an empty RootViewController. My `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
[navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

My IB file for RootViewController just has an empty view.

Nothing unusual. I'm pretty experienced with iOS and that's how I've been doing it every single time. I have no idea what is different this time.

Could someone please advise me? Thanks

Comment: What makes you say that your navigation bar was shifted in any way? From the screenshot you have posted, things look just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set your status-bar-style towards `UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque` and you should get a solid black bar.

To do that, use `setStatusBarStyle:animated:` on your applications' instance:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque 
                                            animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 6.0 the status bar changes color to match the navigation bar, if there is one. This is expected behavior.

Comment: Interesting - I just decided to move into complete iOS 6 dev from 5. Any way to override this? I noticed the same happens when I set a background image. I just looked at some apps and I saw black status bars

Comment: The status-bar analyses the image/color of your navigation bar by "looking" at the top left pixel (if I remember correctly) - deriving its color from that pixels' color value.

Comment: Is there no programatic way to override this? Colored status bars are annoying. I just opened up a few apps that are iOS 6 only and they have custom coloured navigation bars and a black status bar.

Answer (score 2):

Add this code:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

This will make your status bar black again.

You should add it **after** changing the color of your navigation bar.