# UISearchDisplayController Light Instead Of Dark

Tags: ios

How can I change the UISearchDisplayController to be light instead of dark?  Right now my app is like this:

[image: dark]

Whereas the music app is like this (preferable):

[image: light]

I couldn't find any relevant properties or whatnot to change the tint colour.  Here's my relevant code:

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
[searchBar setDelegate:self];
[searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
[searchView addSubview:searchBar];
[self setSearchBar:searchBar];

UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
[searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
[searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
[self setSearchBarDisplayController:searchDisplayController];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was an issue with some UINavigationBar appearance properties that I had set.  Upon removing and changing those, it looks like the navigation bar now works properly.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,
Change the *StatusBarStyle* to **UIStatusBarStyleDefault** & this code is displaying as like you expected.

[image]

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
[searchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
[searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
[searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Search here."];
[searchBar setSearchBarStyle:UISearchBarStyleMinimal];
[searchBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];
```

Comment: Status bar style in Info.plist is UIStatusBarStyleDefault and view controller based status bar appearance is set to NO.  I also have setup the search bar the exact same as your code provided.  Issue is still prevalent.

Comment: @AaronWojnowski then try to place this in & check :     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:NO]; in View cycle method.

Comment: No change.  All that does is change the status bar text colour.  For the record, changing the search bar style to prominent somewhat fixes this but the music app uses minimal so that's definitely not the solution.

Comment: @AaronWojnowski: the same which is working fine here. think StatusBar color changed based on the SearchBar - Refer this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712567/ios-status-bar-changing-color-to-match-navigation-bar-on-its-own